# Firebase - Duplicate credential received

Tags: firebase, facebook, web, safari, firebase-authentication

I have integrated firebase with my PHP based web application.

When I try to login with Facebook, I am getting the following error:

```
code: "auth/internal-error"
message: "Duplicate credential received. Please try again with a new credential."
```

This error occurs when the user has already logged in with Facebook previously.
It shows the following screen (that too only in safari browser) and then the above error occurs.

[image]

Strangely, this error occurs (intermittently) in the Safari browser. It doesn't happen in Chrome browser.